# Goto page in webform or submit

Tags: webforms

I've got a Drupal 8 webform with a multi page wizard. I know that it is possible to "jump" to a specific page if I implement `hook_webform_submission_form_alter()` and add my own submit function to change the formState `current_page` to my desired page. But I want to check a value from a previous page and if the value is value_a I want to submit the form. If it is value_b I want to go to page b and if its value_c I want to go to page c.

```
$pages = $formState->get('pages');

if ($formState->get('type') === 'value_b') {
    $pageName = 'page_b';
    gotoStep($pageName, $pages, $formState); // this is my custom function to go to the desired page
} else if ($formState->get('type') === 'value_c') {
    $pageName = 'page_c';
    gotoStep($pageName, $pages, $formState); // this is my custom function to go to the desired page
} else {
    // SUBMIT FORM. HOW TO DO THIS?
}
```

Comment: Can you not call submitForm or the Webform equivalent? https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormBuilder.php/function/FormBuilder%3A%3AsubmitForm/8.2.x

Comment: The latest dev release of the Webform module for Drupal 8 includes conditional logic support to hide/show (aka skip) wizard pages

Comment: @jrockowitz Sounds great. I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched to the latest dev release ob the webform module and could skip the wizard pages depending on previous values without having to code anything. Thanks for the tip @jrockowitz ;)

Comment: please accept your own answer so the question is solved (now it seems still unresolved).